# Ansible: path to ansible.cfg

Tags: ansible

I have [this](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/11536) known issue. So I try to fix it but I don't see where I have to create my ansible.cfg (or does it already exist)? I tried it in my homedirectory but it still did not work.

```
sudo vi ~/.ansible.cfg
```

I read a lot about /etc/ansible but on my system it isn't there.
I'm on Mac El Capitan. I've installed ansible by using `pip`.

```
ansible --version
ansible 1.9.4
  configured module search path = None
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-configuration-settings-locations):

> Changes can be made and used in a configuration file which will be processed in the following order:
>
> - ANSIBLE_CONFIG (an environment variable)
> - ansible.cfg (in the current directory)
> - .ansible.cfg (in the home directory)
> - /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg

I'm not sure this does 100% apply to 1.9.4. Ansible is terrible in versioning their documentation. (=there only is one version and not always the version a feature was introduced or changed is mentioned)

But I am sure everything except `~/.ansible.cfg` works in 1.x as I have tried that before.

So if you have created `~/.ansible.cfg` and it is not being used, check if the environment var `ANSIBLE_CONFIG` is set or there is one file in the directory from where you call ansible. The first one found will be used. *processed in the following order* does not mean they will be merged in that order. First one found wins.

> I read a lot about /etc/ansible but on my system it isn't there.

Yeah, that depends on how Ansible was installed. If it's not there you could just create it but if you do not need it, no need to create it. I actually deleted mine as I see no use for it.

Comment: This is gold: **processed in the following order does not mean they will be merged in that order. First one found wins.**. As most tools nowadays do merge the configuration  from several files.

Answer (score 15):

For latest version (2.7.6) if you install via pip you wont get ansible folder in /etc.
so this is what you get when you do ansible --version

```
ansible --version
ansible 2.7.6
  config file = None
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
```

But once you manually create directory under /etc as ansible and add ansible.cfg file there ansible automatically detects it. but you will have to configure the rest manually like hosts file..etc . so after this we get

```
ansible --version
ansible 2.7.6
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same thing when I used pip. But I think better way is either using apt or yum according to your OS.
I have centOS so following worked for me.

To get Ansible for CentOS 7, first ensure that the CentOS 7 EPEL repository is installed:

```
sudo yum install epel-release
```

Once the repository is installed, install Ansible with yum:

```
sudo yum install ansible
```

We now have all of the software required to administer our servers through Ansible.

Reference: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-ansible-on-centos-7

Answer (score -1):

With older version of Ansible, you can convert `.ini` files into a dynamic inventory by adding a executable file that have no extentions.

By example for the ini file `this.ini`, create the executable file `this` and enter this in it

```
#! /bin/sh

if [ "$1" == "--host" ]
then
  echo "{" ; echo "}"
  exit 0
fi

ansible-inventory -i $0.ini
exit $?
```

Now, your ini file is added to the dynamic inventory that use the parent directory.